# Date Formatting Moment.js & Display Specific Data from Json File

Tags: jquery, json

First, on `$(value.bd.b).each(function(index, value) {` I am trying to filter out/display only broadcast stations that are only part of the blazers. It currently displays all opponent stations as well. Including other teams stations. Does anyone know how to display just the broadcast that are part of the blazers/pdx? Not sure what would make sense here.

Second, I am using moment.js to change the date format but it is currently not working out. Shows up on the console but then when I go ahead and implement it to my `var filtered = .... currentDate` everything breaks and nothing displays on the browser. Perphaps I am adding it in the wrong spot.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $.getJSON('http://data.nba.com/data/v2015/json/mobile_teams/nba/2020/teams/trail_blazers_schedule_02.json', function(data) {

        var currentDate = moment();
        var newFormat = currentDate.format('dddd, MMM D');
        console.log(newFormat); // <----- shows up on console correctly

        var filtered = data.gscd.g.filter((entry) => Date.parse(entry.gdte) > currentDate); // <----- change to newFormat and it breaks.

        filtered.sort((a, b) => Date.parse(b.gdte) - Date.parse(b.gdte));

        var result = filtered.slice(0,3); 

        var homeOrAway = ($(data.gscd.g.ac).val() === 'Portland') ? 'Home' : 'Away' ;
        
        var gameDetails = '';


        $(result).each(function (index, value) {
            gameDetails += '<div class="row date-section">';
            gameDetails += '<div class="col"><h1>'+value.gdte+'</h1></div>';
            gameDetails += '<div class="col text-end"><a href="#" class="button">WATCH</a></div>';
            gameDetails += '</div>';

            gameDetails += '<div class="row text-center" style="background-color: yellow;">';
            gameDetails += '<div class="col col-details"><img src="assets/pdx-tb-logo.png"/><p>Portland Trail Blazers</p></div>';

            gameDetails += '<div class="col col-details">';
            gameDetails += '<p>'+value.stt+'</p>';
            gameDetails += '<p>'+value.an+'</p>';
            gameDetails += '<p>'+homeOrAway+'</p>';

            $(value.bd.b).each(function(index, value){ //<-- Section that displays all stations.
                // console.log(value.disp);
                gameDetails += '<p>'+value.disp+'</p>';
            });


            gameDetails += '</div>';

            gameDetails += '<div class="col col-details"><img src="assets/pdx-tb-logo.png"/><p>Portland Trail Blazers</p></div>';
            gameDetails += '</div>';
        });

        $('.container').append(gameDetails);

    });

});
```

Comment: Hi, where is `blazers` in your json ?

Comment: @Swati It's a url being pulled in by $.getJSON

Comment: No inside json where is that field because you said in question `out/display only broadcast stations that are only part of the blazers..` ?

Comment: @Swati It is inside the 'bd' array. The broadcasts are defined by 'disp'. So 'gscd' > 'g' > select any object > 'bd' > 'b' > select any object > 'disp'. I hope that helps answer your question. I am wanting to display 'disp' that are blazer/pdx based only. But as you can see they are very nested. I am only currently able to display ALL 'disp'. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Actually still i didn't got . It would be more easy to understand if you can show excepted  output as well :)

Comment: @Swati So I want to display the broadcasts that are local to Portland ONLY. That would be under 'disp' in the JSON file but the disp changes depending on if the game is a home game or an anyway game. So the local Portland broadcast stations now are 'NBC Sports Northwest' and 'Rip City Radio 620' they live under 'disp' in the JSON file so those are the ONLY ONES that should display. Nothing else. Does that make sense now? I know this is a lot, that is why I am having a hard time lol the logic is too complex for my knowledge of extracting certain data for JSON. Thank you for you help as well :)

Comment: @Swati This is the JSON file. This is where this data lives http://data.nba.com/data/v2015/json/mobile_teams/nba/2020/teams/trail_blazers_schedule_02.json

Comment: Somewhat i got so there is two type `"type":"tv"` and `"type"radio"` you need to display json where `"type":"tv"`  or `"scope":"home"` ?

Comment: @Swati You got it! The 'scope' changes depending on if it is a home game (played in Portland Moda Stadium) or if it is an away game. That is why my logic gets all messed up. Because it depends and changes on that. It is not always home, sometimes it is 'away.' I have tried the logic where if ```an: Moda Center``` then only display ``disp`` if ```scope: home``` that would be the logic behind it but maybe I am not writing it correctly. I hope that helps you more :)

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the `scope` is `home` or `away` depending on this show only that values. Also, use `moment(value.gdte).format('dddd, MMM D')` to show date in required format.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$.getJSON('http://data.nba.com/data/v2015/json/mobile_teams/nba/2020/teams/trail_blazers_schedule_02.json', function(data) {

  var currentDate = moment();
  var newFormat = currentDate.format('dddd, MMM D');
  console.log(newFormat);

  var filtered = data.gscd.g.filter((entry) => Date.parse(entry.gdte) > currentDate);
  filtered.sort((a, b) => Date.parse(b.gdte) - Date.parse(b.gdte));
  var result = filtered.slice(0, 3);
  var homeOrAway = ($(data.gscd.g[0].ac).val() === 'Portland') ? 'Home' : 'Away';

  var gameDetails = '';


  $(result).each(function(index, value) {
    //format your date
    gameDetails += '<div class="row date-section">';
    gameDetails += '<div class="col"><h1>' + moment(value.gdte).format('dddd, MMM D') + '</h1></div>';
    gameDetails += '<div class="col text-end"><a href="#" class="button">WATCH</a></div>';
    gameDetails += '</div>';

    gameDetails += '<div class="row text-center" style="background-color: yellow;">';
    gameDetails += '<div class="col col-details"><img src="assets/pdx-tb-logo.png"/><p>Portland Trail Blazers</p></div>';

    gameDetails += '<div class="col col-details">';
    gameDetails += '<p>' + value.stt + '</p>';
    gameDetails += '<p>' + value.an + '</p>';
    gameDetails += '<p>' + homeOrAway + '</p>';

    $(value.bd.b).each(function(index, value) {
      //check if scope is same if yes only append that values
      if (value.scope == homeOrAway.toLowerCase()) {
        gameDetails += '<p>' + value.disp + '</p>';
      }
    });


    gameDetails += '</div>';

    gameDetails += '<div class="col col-details"><img src="assets/pdx-tb-logo.png"/><p>Portland Trail Blazers</p></div>';
    gameDetails += '</div>';
  });

  $('.container').append(gameDetails);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-qTXRIMyZIFb8iQcfjXWCO8+M5Tbc38Qi5WzdPOYZHIlZpzBHG3L3by84BBBOiRGiEb7KKtAOAs5qYdUiZiQNNQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! One thing is that the Feb 9th is actually a 'home' game since it is played in Portland (```ac:Portland```). The broadcast should only pull stations that have to do with Portland. These are Florida stations. That is what got me as well. So that is just the one problem. The other parts are perfect! :D Would you know how to tell it that if it is a home/Portland game to show only Portland Stations? I was just going to add it in manually/hardcoded but that would not be appropriate in case stations change or get added you know?

Comment: Hi see what does `$(data.gscd.g[0].ac).val()` gives you ? and if the selector correct